# How to run five commands in one sh file?

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, shell-script

I'm working in Cygwin terminal
when i choose in cygwin terminal

```
./test2.sh
```

it split my files and in second step should execute the remaining commands but it stops

> bellow content of my **test2.sh** file

```
echo -n "1 - Split files"
split -a 4 -d -l 100 d:/test/*.* c:/test/;

echo -n "2 - Add txt extension"
find C:/test/ -type f  ! -name "*.*" -exec mv {} {}.txt \;

echo -n "3 - Delete unnecessary characters"
sed -i -e '/Details (spedition)/d' -e 's/Value (eur): //g' -e 's/Number (price): //g' C:/test/*.txt;

echo -n "4 - Read only"
chattr +r C:/test/*.*;

echo -n "5 - Pack everything into 7 zip"
cygstart C:/test/7zip_script.bat
exit
```

for now only this work

```
 echo -n "1 - Split files"
 split -a 4 -d -l 100 d:/test/*.* c:/test/;
```

each command separately (copy paste separately) works beautifully

why not work together?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: WIthout a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) what actually executes the script is anyone's guess.

Comment: In your second command, you probably want a `\!` instead of a bare `!`. Otherwise your shell is probably taking it as a broken attempt at history substitution and eating it (not passing it to `find` as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a proper `shebang` on the first line and use
`/cygdrive/X/` for disks instead of `X:`, as not all program
will manage it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo -n "1 - Split files"
split -a 4 -d -l 100 /cygdrive/d/test/*.* /cygdrive/c/test/;

echo -n "2 - Add txt extension"
find /cygdrive/c/test/ -type f  ! -name "*.*" -exec mv {} {}.txt \;

echo -n "3 - Delete unnecessary characters"
sed -i -e '/Details (spedition)/d' -e 's/Value (eur): //g' -e 's/Number (price): //g' /cygdrive/c/test/*.txt;

echo -n "4 - Read only"
chattr +r /cygdrive/c/test/*.*;

echo -n "5 - Pack everything into 7 zip"
cygstart /cygdrive/c/test/7zip_script.bat
exit
```

If does not work, please provide the error messages.
Of course set the script permission for execution with

```
chmod +x your_script_file_name
```

Comment: in addition after the shebang he can set `set -x` just to see the script in action, and see where it hangs..